# Communicating between iPhone and Mac

Tags: ios, macos, networking, bluetooth

I'm planning on creating an app that takes data from an iPhone and sends it to another application on the Mac. Gyroscope data will also be sent.

I'm assuming that this should best be done over a bluetooth connection.

Could anyone please give me some information as to how I should structure the apps or if it is possible?

Comment: According to my researches there is not the possibility to send custom data over bluetooth. You have to use a wi-fi connection.

Comment: How about using Bonjour?

Comment: Bonjour seems possible. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3901659/how-to-send-data-from-iphone-over-wifi-to-application-to-print-message agrees.

Comment: Bluetooth is possible. Bonjour uses it. My own app uses it through bonjour.

Comment: I guess the question would be Bonjour through Bluetooth or Bonjour through wifi? Bluetooth seems like it would be faster

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Id say the most ideal way to accomplish this is via the Bonjour protocol.

Here is a great article on the subject, http://mobileorchard.com/tutorial-networking-and-bonjour-on-iphone/.

Good thing with using Bonjour in iOS is it also works via Bluetooth.

Hope this helps !

Comment: I guess I'd be using `CFNetwork`.  And that's compatible with OS X I believe. Perfect!

Answer (score 4):

Here I have created sample application which exchange the data between iphone and iMAC.

I have tested only with wifi.

https://github.com/boobalaninfo/Bonjour-iOS-MAC-Apps