# How do I send values from an iOS app to a Mac app?

Tags: ios, macos, bonjour, continuity

I would like to send a stream of values from an iPhone app using the accelerometer, to an associated Mac app.

I currently have it working with Bonjour, as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10969666/communicating-between-iphone-and-mac) but there is no user authentication with this, so I don't see Apple being ok with it, I guess anyone could intercept the data.

Is it possible to do this with Continuity? Any other possibilities? Or is Bonjour the best solution?

Comment: This link might help https://www.raywenderlich.com/84174/ios-8-handoff-tutorial

Comment: Thanks @Malik, just trying that now. Can't seem to get it working on the Mac app on the moment, but if I do will be good to see how often the values are sent between devices...